# Dell Mini 10 with Ubuntu - touchpad issues

Tags: ubuntu, touchpad, netbook

I just recently got a Dell Mini 10 (not a 10v) and I installed Ubuntu 9.04 (regular, not the netbook version)

All works well except the touchpad is jumpy as all get out.   It seems like the mouse is jumping around like crazy when using the touchpad.  Is there anything I can do to either calibrate it better or change the driver?

Comment: does this only occur on battery power?

Comment: No, on both battery and plugged-in power.  If I plug in a normal USB mouse it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following steps:

- Check if you have the Synaptics Touchpad enabled via *System->Preferences->Touchpad*
- If that menu item isn't present, or you get an error about SHMConfig, follow the Ubuntu Community documentation on [how to configure the touchpad](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad). Note: You will have to reboot after adding the SHMConfig entry in the shmconfig.fdi file.
- Configure the Touchpad sensitivity from the Touchpad menu entry.

Answer (score 1):

elantech linux driver  Is the driver you will need.  Synaptics dont work by itself well. well on the Dell Mini 10.  See this forum post for more details. http://www.mydellmini.com/forum/dell-mini-10-discussion/10961-mini-10-touchpad-ubuntu-driver.html